# monochromatic and mesh style of 3d plotting

Tags: plotting

how to adjust the mesh and monochromatic plot to be same as this
[image]

Comment: Please post the *Mathematica* code that you are using, then look up *Mesh*, *Plot3D*, and related pages in the documentation. Try what you find there out, and if it doesn't work, include that code in your post.

Comment: And try to play with Plot3D options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I share the sentiment that this question should have shown a lot more effort. Nonetheless, plot styling is quite possibly the most maddening and least intuitive aspect of *Mathematica*, at least in my opinion. The sheer quantity of options is daunting.

With that in mind, here is a way to achieve something similar to what the OP requested, to get started.

```
Plot3D[
  Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  Mesh -> 40, PlotPoints -> 75, PlotRange -> All,

  (* Add grids to the back of the plotting box *)
  FaceGrids -> {{0, 1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}},
  FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.7], Dashing[0.01]],

  (* Sets surface colors *)
  PlotStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.8]],
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}},

  (* Controls shape of graph,perspective *)
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.8}, ViewPoint -> {125, -100, 60}, 
  ViewAngle -> All, ImageSize -> Full,

  (* Axis labels etc *)
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, FontSize -> 18] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"})
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Ahmed You are welcome. I hope this helps as a starting point for your own customizations.